# Converting $\frac{dB\mu A}{m}$ to $\frac{dB\mu V}{m}$?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, antennas

I am trying to convert $\frac{dB\mu A}{m}$ to $\frac{dB\mu V}{m}$

So, I know that;

$\frac{dB\mu V}{m}$ = $\frac{dB\mu A}{m} + 51.5$

However, I cannot find a source explains where 51.5 comes from. Is it related with air impedence? Thank you for explanations in advance.

Comment: What are $d$, $B$, $\mu$, $A$, and $m$?

Comment: dB = decibel
$\mu$ = micro
A = ampere
V = Volt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the freespace impedance, convert it to same scale (20*log10(377Ω)) = 51.5

In dB multiplication becomes adition, realizing this, you have something that looks like ohms law.